Perturbations of Schwarzschild Metric
I am reading Luciano Rezzolla's lecture notes on Gravitational waves from Perturbed Black Holes and Relativistic Stars. Link. In sections 2.2 and 2.3, he splits the metric perturbation components into tensor spherical harmonics of even and odd parity, and treats them separately to obtain the Regge-Wheeler and Zerilli equations for the odd and even parity parts, respectively. These equations resemble wave equations, albeit with potential functions, much like Schrodinger equation of quantum mechanics. He cites the 1957 paper of T. Regge and J. A. Wheeler. I have tried to go through this paper, and consequently to the Wikipedia article to understand the vector spherical harmonics, in order to understand the form of the $h_{\mu\nu}$ matrix, and in particular, exactly how it is constructed, and the derivations of the expressions of the components of the perturbation matrix. However, I don't understand exactly how these expressions were derived. My wish is to understand and interpret the Regge-Wheeler and Zerilli equations and their nuances, such as the QNMs.

If someone could do a derivation of just the (0,3) component of the perturbation matrix, I think I could pick up the idea and try to do the rest. Or if someone could suggest some resource or lectures where this is done or at least, hinted.
